# Why I'm gettting NED consistency problem during INET installation?

Tags: omnet++, veins, inet

[Inet installation](https://i.stack.imgur.com/f74bb.png)

OS: Windows 10
OMNET++ 5.6
INET 4.2

```
'pathLoss.breakpointDistance': no such parameter    Ieee802154NarrowbandScalarRadioMedium.ned   /inet/src/inet/physicallayer/ieee802154/packetlevel line 32 
NED Consistency Problem
```

```
'receiver.sensitivity': no such parameter   Ieee80211Radio.ned  /inet/src/inet/physicallayer/ieee80211/packetlevel  line 52 NED Consistency Problem
```

Comment: Could you edit your question, provide [mcve] and clearly express your problem? Now it is difficult to understand your question.

Comment: Yes sir I'm getting NED consistancy warnings while installing INET I don't know how to solve them.

Comment: Sir can you able to see the error image there? because I couldn't able to copy the warnings from there

Comment: Could you edit your question and provide more details about your OS, version of OMNeT++, version of INET, steps you are doing for installing INET? Actually, the attached image presents warnings, not errors - these warning are usually false positive and you may ignore them.

Comment: okay Sir .I'm using windows 10 OS, OMNET++ 5.6, INET 4.2 and I'm directly installing it from system built in I mean when I open new workspace there I will get one INET installation option right?? through that only I'm installing but getting so many warnings so Is those warnings affect my further VEINS or vanet installation?

Comment: If you want to quickly check how a correct installation of Veins and INET looks like: Instant Veins is a virtual machine that has both set up and configured fully.

Comment: From my experience so far with OMNeT++ and INET, those warnings don't affect the simulations in any way.